# Difference between addListener() and addCallback() to ListenableFuture

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency, guava

I am a beginner in Java concurrent library and learning to use ListenableFuture in my code. I went through this [document](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) and still confused about which one is the preferred way of registering runnable code to my ListenableFuture object:

**`future.addListener(Runnable, Executor)`** vs **`Futures.addCallback(ListenableFuture<V>, FutureCallback<V>, Executor)`**

It will be really helpful if someone can throw light on performance, use-cases, and which one to prefer over others!

Comment: Some more information may help in the following link but it does not answer everything https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html

Answer (score 3):

the difference is that for `addListener` you supply `Runnable`, and for `addCallback` you sipply `FutureCallback`. `Runnable` is not provided with the result, so if you need it, you have to make additional efforts.

In short, if you want to use future's result, use `addCallback`, otherwise use `addListener`.

Comment: We can use the future's result in addListener() also. Just have an anonymous Runnable object and work with Future's result.

Comment: anonymous Runnable is in fact a new class which implements Runnable. That is, you have to make additional efforts, as I said.